# How to make whole overlay region clickable

Tags: javascript, css

I don't know how to make the blue region clickable,

Now, only the **RED region** is clickable

[here's the demo page](http://balance-cafe.4am-lesson.com:3000/)

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure here. You want the blue area to be clickable just like the red area, so when you click the blue area, you get redirected like you clicked the red area? (hope that made any sence)

Comment: @PatrickR yes, this is what i meant

Comment: a fast and not great, but functional soulution could be to add a onClick=" " in the "image-overlay" div. and inside the onClick, make a JS redirect. also remember to set the curser to pointer when it hover the "image-overlay" so people know it can be clicked

Also as @notulysses said, you can make a link tag, and set the div's inside it, to make everything redirect to the right place